# The sneakiest of questions, how has this stayed open

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Check out this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870928/rise-of-netbooks-and-programming

even the title screams close me, yet it has managed to stay open and even got a few upvotes!

Surely this question is massively off topic. Its not about programming and although has started a bunch of discussion it doesn't seem to me like it conforms to the SO standards for questions.

**What is the best procedure to bring this to light so that it can be closed?**

Comment: It was asked clear back in 2009 when moderation wasn't as tough.

Comment: That's not "a bunch of upvotes". If it had more upvotes (say a few hundred), it would've been noticed earlier and destroyed as part of the numerous witch-hunts that we do.

Comment: Some times these just slip through the cracks. When you see them, vote to close.

Comment: Cool, I was wondering whether flagging or voting to close was the correct procedure. I might add this to the question here to make it more answerable.

Comment: Dropping a link in the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta) will usually get it closed pretty quick.

Comment: Sir @Mysticial, we found a witch^H^H^H^H^H old question. May we burn her^H^H^H it?

Comment: @dmckee: ^W is much less work.

Comment: @0x7fffffff Hey, i know this is old, but your comment seems to be the most appropriate answer to this question ... You should add it and i will accept so we can finish up here.

Answer (score 5):

Nuked.

No, it's not worth keeping around. Animuson closed it, I've deleted it.